# How to instantiate/setup a plugin (VGit) in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, plugin-nvim-r

I am new to NeoVim and slowly converting to it as my main tool of choice for editing and development in general.
I came across the [VGit plugin](https://github.com/tanvirtin/vgit.nvim) and decided to give it a try but the [setup](https://github.com/tanvirtin/vgit.nvim#setup) section literally says:

```
You must instantiate the plugin in order for the features to work.
      require('vgit').setup()
```

I have 0 ideas where to "set this up" or how to instantiate a plugin in nVim.
I have tried searching but to no avail.
I would appreciate some pointer in this regard.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's assuming lua. You can ask the maintainers, but probably you have to (at some point when the plugin's directories are available on the equivalent of `runtimepath`) do either `lua require('vgit').setup()` in your init.vim or just `require('vgit').setup()` in init.lua

Comment: I actually put that line in my `init.vim` but nvim complained about the line. Though not without prefiixing it with `lua` will try that and see if that works.

Comment: init.vim runs vimscript; to get to lua you need various prefixes (IIRC, I run vim). Try `:help lua` maybe

Comment: try using init.lua

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt in the init.vim config file?

Comment: no, you want to use lua, so you have to use the lua init file